# Passing a variable to an include to set an image transform throws Setting Unknown Property error

Tags: templating, image-transforms, variable, include

I'm using an entry field to set an image transform handle:

```
{% set format = block.imageCrop %}
```

Then I'm trying to pass that to an include:

```
{% include 'partials/_img' with { format: format } %}
```

This is the _img template:

```
{% do image.setTransform(format) %}
{{ tag('img', {
  src: image.url,
  width: image.width,
  height: image.height,
  srcset: image.getSrcset(['1.5x', '2x', '3x']),
  alt: image.alt ? image.alt : image.title,
}) }}
```

This is causing this error: "Setting unknown property: craft\models\ImageTransform::label"

If I change my include to the name of a transform -- with { format: 'square' } -- it works fine.

I'm not sure what the issue is here -- is there an error in my syntax?
I have other instances of this include where I do manually specify the transform, rather than using a custom field (with { format: 'square' }), so ideally, I'd like to be able to do it both ways.

Comment: If you're using an entries field, you probably have to do `block.imageCrop.one()`.

Comment: It’s just a drop-down field in an entry. I edited the post to clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dropdown fields don't return the selected option as a string. Instead, they return a [`SingleOptionFieldData` object](https://docs.craftcms.com/api/v4/craft-fields-data-singleoptionfielddata.html) that you can use to access the value of the selected option as well as its label. The `setTransform` method doesn't know what to do with that object, so you get an error.

This will give you the value of the selected option as a string:

```twig
{% set format = block.imageCrop.value %}
```

Keep in mind that this may return null if no option is selected, so you may want to set a default:

```twig
{% set format = block.imageCrop.value | default('square') %}
```

In general, if you're not sure what's going on in your template, dumping the value of variables with the [`dd` tag](https://craftcms.com/docs/4.x/dev/tags.html#dd) is a good way to find out:

```twig
{% set format = block.imageCrop %}
{% dd format %}
```

This will show you that you're dealing with an object instead of a string in this case.

Comment: That did it. I didn't know about the dd tag. Thanks!